# What's the difference between an accessory and an accomplice?

Tags: criminal-law, legal-terms, definition

What are the definitions of each and what exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

The guys with the guns robbing the bank are accomplices, the guy driving the getaway car is an accessory.

Answer (score 1):

In English and Welsh law, they mean the same thing.

> Those who help others commit crimes have been
> known by a number of different legal terms: accessories, secondary parties, or accomplices.<sup>2</sup>
> These terms all mean the same thing.

> <sup>2</sup> At one point the common law distinguished between principals in the second degree (those who were
> assisting the principal and were present when the offence was committed) and accessories before the fact
> (those whose participation was limited to activities before the crime was committed). The law no longer
> draws this distinction.

Jonathan Herring, *Criminal Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (2020 9 ed). 837.

> The simplest way of drawing this distinction is to say that a principal is a person whose
> acts fall within the legal definition of the crime, whereas an accomplice (sometimes
> called an ‘accessory’ or ‘secondary party’) is anyone who aids, abets, counsels, or
> procures a principal.<sup>10</sup>

> <sup>10</sup> *Gnango* [2011] UKSC 59, para 129 (Lord Kerr).

*Ashworth's Principles of Criminal Law* (2020 9 ed). p 455.

Answer (score 0):

An accessory does not commit any physical criminal act, but helps the perpetrator before the latter commits a crime.

Answer (score -1):

An accessory helps the perpetrator commit the crime. An accomplice is a co-perpetrator.

Comment: So they are the same?

Comment: Is ryan hold an accessory or an accomplice?